# Homework - algebra, find constants

Tags: arithmetic, factorial

The question is as follows, I think I solved it partially:

Show that there are $a,b$ real positive numbers such that

$an^7 \leq \frac{n!}{7!(n-7)!} \leq bn^7$

$7\leq n$

my solution for b:

$\frac{n!}{7!(n-7)!} \leq \frac{n!}{(n-7)!} = (n-6)(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)(n) \leq n*n*n*n*n*n*n = n^7$ so $b=1$ is a good answer for b.

But for a...I'm stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge7$, $n-k\ge n/7$ for $0\le k\le6$

So $$\frac{n!}{7!(n-7)!} =\frac{(n-6)(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n}{7!}\ge \frac{n^7}{7!7^7}$$

$$a=\frac{1}{7!7^7}$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you said is untrue for large values of n. $\frac{(n-6)(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n}{7!}$ isnt larger than $\frac{n^7}{7!*7^7}$ for all values of n.

Comment: Can you tell the value of $n$ for which it is false?

Comment: My calculator won't show numbers that high :) But generally speaking, $n^7$ is a lot larger than $(n-6)(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n$ as $n$ grows.

Comment: ok, what part of my proof do you think is false?

Comment: $\frac{(n-6)(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n}{7!}\ge \frac{n^7}{7!7^7}$ I don't see why this is true. And I think that as $n$ grows and approaches infinity, the ${7^7}$ added in the denumenator isn't enough and the right hand side will be larger than the left hand side.

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n−6)(n−5)(n−4)(n−3)(n−2)(n−1)n}{n^7}=1$?

Comment: Point well made :) Thank you.